# How would you use a DVCS (mercurial in my case) to develop for different versions of the .NET framework?

Tags: .net, asp.net, version-control, mercurial, dvcs

I'm writing some sort of new adminstration dashboard for our cms (which runs on asp.net webforms). Some of our older servers can only handle .NET 2.0 for various reasons so I'd have to rewrite my code which uses lambda expressions etc. for that.

I wonder how you would use a dvcs like mercurial to develop those two versions concurrently.

My current codebase and mercurial repository is targeted at .NET 3.5. I'm relatively new to mercurial and I guess I'd have to branch the codebase?

Any best practices or tutorials?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can use Mercurial for this. Here is how it would work.

Let's say that your current clone is called `new-dot-net` since it
support the new .Net version. You make a clone of it and call it
`old-dot-net` or something like that. The two clones are now identical
and both target .Net 3.5.

Now carefully make small changes in `old-dot-net` in order to make it
.Net 2.0 compatible. When you make the changes the two clones will
start to diverge:

```
new-dot-net: ... [a] --- [b]

old-dot-net: ... [a] --- [b] --- [c] --- [d]
```

Here you made `[c]` and `[d]` changesets to add the .Net 2.0
compatibility. Notice how the `old-dot-net` clone contains more
changesets than `new-dot-net` since it has the backwards compatibility
changes that you *dont* want to see in `new-dot-net`. As you continue
working, it is important to think of this: `net-dot-net` will contain
a subset of the changesets in `old-dot-net`. The changes flow from
`new-dot-net` to `old-dot-net`, but *never* in the opposite direction.

Let's say you make a new change in `new-dot-net`. You make the change
in `new-dot-net` and the situation now looks like this:

```
new-dot-net: ... [a] --- [b] --- [x]

old-dot-net: ... [a] --- [b] --- [c] --- [d]
```

You now want to back-port the change to `old-dot-net` as well, you
change to `old-dot-net` and pull from `net-dot-net`:

```
% cd old-dot-net
% hg pull ../new-dot-net
```

This will create a [new head](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Head) in `old-dot-net`:

```
                             [x]
                            /
old-dot-net: ... [a] --- [b] --- [c] --- [d]
```

since the `[x]` changeset has `[b]` as it's parent changeset. You now
have [multiple heads](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MultipleHeads) and have to merge to reduce the number of
heads. By merging you create a new changeset which is your way of
saying "this is how `[x]` and `[d]` should be combined". If the `[x]`
changeset only touches code which is not also touched in `[c]` and
`[d]`, then the merge should just work. Otherwise you'll be presented
with a merge tool and have to resolve the conflict. You commit the
merge as chageset `[e]`:

```
                             [x] --------------.
                            /                   \
old-dot-net: ... [a] --- [b] --- [c] --- [d] --- [e]
```

And you're done -- you have now incorporated the `[x]` change into
your .Net 2.0 compatible code.

You repeat this every time there has been a change in `new-dot-net`.
Let's say that more features are added:

```
new-dot-net: ... [a] --- [b] --- [x] --- [y] --- [z]
```

After pulling them into `old-dot-net` you get

```
                             [x] --------------.---- [y] --- [z]
                            /                   \
old-dot-net: ... [a] --- [b] --- [c] --- [d] --- [e]
```

And you now merge `[e]` and `[z]`:

```
                             [x] --------------.---- [y] --- [z]
                            /                   \               \
old-dot-net: ... [a] --- [b] --- [c] --- [d] --- [e] ----------- [f]
```

The important parts to remember are these:

- make any **new features** in `new-dot-net`.
- **pull** changes into `old-dot-net`
- **never push** from `old-dot-net` to `new-dot-net`.

Should you at some point find that a change in `new-dot-net` is not
needed in `old-dot-net`, then you still need to pull it in and merge
it. But you will then do a *dummy merge*. If the heads are `[w]` and
`[g]`, and you want keep `[g]`, then do

```
% HGMERGE=true hg merge -y
% hg revert --all --rev g
% hg commit -m 'Dummy merge with y.'
```

The [trick](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Keep_.22My.22_or_.22Their.22_files_when_doing_a_merge) is to do the merge without caring about the results,
then revert all changes, and commit the unchanged working copy as the
merge. That way you tell the world that "the combination of `[w]` and
`[g]` is `[g]`", i.e., you throw away the changes in `[w]`. New
changes made in `new-dot-net` after `[w]` can then be merged like
normal.

Comment: so you wouldnt use branches for this? why not?

Comment: It makes no difference -- there is a 1-1 relationship between (named) branches and clones in Mercurial. So for the purpose of back-porting changes it doesn't make things easier or harder. With clones it might be easier to compare files from two clones (by opening them both in your editor) and the separation makes explanations like the above easier, IMHO.

Comment: This is a great explanation of the dummy merge technique.  I'm going to bookmark this.  Thanks again!